# Karma: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, karma-runner

I am running Karma on my yeoman based angularjs app.

I get the following error when running "grunt karma":

> ```
> Chrome 28.0 (Mac) ERROR
>     Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>     at myNgApp/admin/app/scripts/bootstrap.min.js:6
> Chrome 28.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.206 secs / 0 secs)
> ```

When I launch the app on my browser via "grunt server", everything seems fine. There are no errors on the console either.

My `index.html` also imports `jquery.min.js` before any other JavaScript file. Any idea what is going on?

**Update:** I have a feeling the the command `grunt karma` is looking through all the files in my scripts directory. Bootstrap is one of the first ones, and it probably loads that before jQuery, and hence the error.

If this is the case, how do I stop this?

Comment: it *looks* like either bootstrap is being loaded before jQuery is loaded, or something is overriding jQuery before bootstrap is included.

Comment: please show us your HTML head.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Did you load jQuery in the karma.conf.js?

This is how my list looks:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/moment/moment.js',
  'app/bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'app/bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/ng-infinite-scroll.js',
  'app/bower_components/parametrizedLocation/dist/parametrizedLocation.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
],
```