# Karma tests succeed but PhantomJS returns "An error was thrown in afterAll" SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

All our karma unit tests seem to succeed in our automated build, but the PhantomJS runner returns a non-zero result to the build framework (TeamCity). The only error I can find in the logs is:

```
[17:53:31][JavaScript Unit Tests] PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8.0.0) ERROR
[17:53:31][JavaScript Unit Tests]   An error was thrown in afterAll
[17:53:31][JavaScript Unit Tests]   SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','
```

The project is using:

- AngularJS@1.4.8
- karma@4.1.0
- npm@6.9.0
- Node.js@v12.3.1

karma.conf.js:

```
// Karma Configuration
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
        files: [
            "scripts/vendor/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js",
            "scripts/vendor/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js",
            "scripts/vendor/*.js",
            "scripts/angular/**/*.module.js",
            "scripts/angular/**/*.app.js",
            "scripts/angular/**/*.js",
            "scripts/angular/**/spec/*.spec.js"
        ],
        exclude: [
            "scripts/vendor/angular-1*.js",
            "scripts/vendor/angular-animate.js",
            "scripts/angular/anycastManagementApp/anycastManagement.app.js",
            "scripts/angular/cart/**/.js",
            "scripts/angular/cart/*.js",
            "scripts/vendor/bootstrap.min.js",
            "scripts/angular/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/**/*.*"
        ],
        plugins: [
            "karma-jasmine",
            "karma-jasmine-matchers",
            "karma-chrome-launcher",
            "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
            "karma-teamcity-reporter",
            "karma-spec-reporter",
            "karma-coverage"
        ],
        frameworks: ["jasmine", "jasmine-matchers"],
        port: 9000,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        client: {
            jasmine: {
                random: false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Things I've tried:

- Several different versions of karma/Node.js.
- Some similar questions suggested that there is a race condition in our tests, and we should disable karma's default random ordering, but that didn't help.
- There is no async anywhere in our .spec.js files.

My next steps: I suppose I'll begin disabling individual tests to see if any of them have an influence on this afterAll outcome.

Update: disabling all the tests via xdescribe didn't resolve the error. So I know the error is not related to the tests themselves but to some bug or incompatibility in the plugins/libraries.

Comment: These always suck. They end up being an error in the libraries you're using rather than your own code. I feel like it's not always like this, but sometimes when it is, it sucks :P Very good question though, well formatted.

Comment: @FeaturedSpace Yup :-| The problem started happening seemingly without any changes to the tests or pages on our part. At first it was an intermittent "karma not found" error, which I resolved by updating Node.js/npm/karma to newer versions. But I think there is an incompatibility in one of those new versions (or one of the karma plugins).

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I would have downgraded my node, npm, and karma rather than update, because now you probably have to wait for Phantom to update. If I do answer this I'll probably just reference you to PhantomJS update notes? XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently PhantomJS hasn't been updated since 2016 (v2.1.1) and is not an active project. It seems that the [recommendation](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/27/phantomjs-is-dead-use-chrome-headless-in-continuous-integration.html) is to [replace PhantomJS in your projects with ChromeHeadless](https://medium.com/@metalex9/replace-phantomjs-with-headless-chromium-for-javascript-unit-testing-in-karma-59812e6f8ce4).

Even the PhantomJS maintainer, Vitaliy Slobodin, said about ChromeHeadless:

> I think people will switch to it, eventually. Chrome is faster and
>   more stable than PhantomJS. And it doesn’t eat memory like crazy.

It would have been nice to find a headless browser that wasn't dependent on Google, but apparently PhantomJS was using a WebKit-based engine anyway, so we're not really losing any browser variety/breadth by making this change.

Following the instructions in the linked articles, my issue went away, sort of. I did run into another similar [afterAll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242580/karma-uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined) related to a missing library reference. I suspect that this was the same error as with PhantomJS but was not being reported correctly. After switching to ChromeHeadless, the error was reported correctly and was easy to fix.